# How do I mount an EFS endpoint on /etc/fstab with using Cloud Formation in User-data section?

Tags: bash, aws-cloudformation, amazon-efs

When I write a bash command on User-data section in CloudFormation template EFS endpoint is not inserted in the `/etc/fstab/`.

My bash command looks like this:

```
echo "$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone).${EfsFileSystem}.efs.aws-region.amazonaws.com:/ /mnt/ nfs4 nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
```

I have to mount the endpoint using

```
mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport fs-fbxxxx.efs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:/ /mnt/
```

Comment: Please add the user-data code in the question that you are trying to insert.

Comment: @Ashutosh i have added in description section. please have a look.

Comment: anything in the linux messages (like error messages. .) ?

Comment: @gusto2 there is not placing EFS sysytem-ID on /etc/fstab path. it would be comma, colon types of issue. but i can not recognise it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a working example of mounting EFS via UserData here
https://github.com/Bit-Clouded/Glenlivet/blob/master/platforms/ecs-base.template#L275

```
          #!/bin/bash
          apt-get update -qqy && apt-get install -qqy nfs-common
          EC2_AVAIL_ZONE=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone`
          DIR_SRC=$EC2_AVAIL_ZONE.${SharedDiskGp}.efs.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com
          mkdir /mnt/efs
          echo -e "$DIR_SRC:/ /mnt/efs nfs defaults 0 0" | tee -a /etc/fstab
          mount -a
          # restart docker service so efs mount can come into effect.
          service docker restart
```

Copied the relevant bit here as per SO guideline.